# Flutter Firebase filter data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to use `where` and `orderBy` simultaneously in Flutter Firebase? My app doesn't allow me to. When I do it it throws an error. But when I use only one of it it works well.

```
StreamBuilder(
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(widget.userCollection)
        .where("Status", isEqualTo: "Verified")
        .orderBy("FirstName", descending: false)
        .snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot){
         if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
             return const CircularProgressIndicator();}
         if (snapshot.hasError) {
             return Text(widget.errorString);} 
         if (!snapshot.hasData) {
             return Center(
                child: Text(widget.noUsersyetString),);}
         else{
            //The rest of the code
            }
         }
       )
```

Comment: What's the error your app throws? (going forward, please include such information right away)

Comment: The problem is it doesn't print the error even when I added (print(snapshot.error)). It only shows the error on the screen where I have
if (snapshot.hasError) {
             return Text(widget.errorString);}

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, but if you get an error -> ensure that it is in the question. Without that, we can't help you solve that error.